# Where is this extra space between divs coming from?

Tags: html, space

http://www.lethalmonk6.byethost24.com/index.html

If you inspect with firebug the spacing between the "project-link" divs, there are a few pixels of added margin between each div. I have the margin set to 20 px, and then these little bits gets added on. Where is it coming from?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're using `display:inline-block` so the white space between the elements is what you are seeing there. You can either remove the white space between the divs or use `float: left` instead.

To elaborate... if you're using `display: inline-block` do this:

```
<div></div><div></div>
```

Instead of this:

```
<div></div>
<div></div> // White space is added because of the new line
```

Comment: Is there a way I can remove the space?

Comment: Yes, by actually making the divs adjacent in your markup without any spaces or line breaks between them. See my added example...

Answer (score 1):

As Terminal Frost said, add `float: left` to the class, and remove `display: inline-block`. Additionally, add `content: "."` to the parent div container to fix the wrapping issue you'll have from doing that.

Comment: content: "." doesnt really fix my wrapping issue, maybe I am not using it correctly?

Comment: You should put `content: "."` on the `<div id="container">` element.

Answer (score 1):

As Lucifer Sam said, `display:inline-block` will show you space between element if there are one.

The slution given is good:

```
<div></div><div></div>
```

But for element with large content, i personnaly prefer this solution of not having the white space between `display:inline-block` elements. This is what i do:

```
   <div>
       large content
   </div><!-- No space
--><div>
       large content 2
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't quite happy with the provided solutions here and then I came across a fix that I actually was using to address this issue before, but forgot about it...

All you might need is to simply add `font-size: 0;` to the parent container (you can overwrite this rule for the children, so it shouldn't break your fonts).

So, here's a basic example:

```
<div class="font-zero">
    <div class="inline-block"></div>
    <div class="inline-block"></div>
    <div class="inline-block"></div>
</div>

<style>
    .font-zero { font-size: 0; }
    .inline-block { display: inline-block; }
</style>
```

With that example you don't have to worry about the markup in your code (personally, I think removing line breaks in the code to solve this issue is really ugly) and also you don't need to use floating, which might be not optimal for many reasons.

Since this page was the first Google result, I hope I'll get here next time I come across this issue and forget the easy fix... And maybe it would be useful for someone else too :)

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled here and my solution was to set `overflow: hidden;` on one of the elements that in my case was using `filter: blur(5px);`.